# Unable to access the updated global variable's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Suppose I have two Python files:

1. `abc.py`:

```py
from .config import *
update_a()
print_a() # prints 5
print(a)  # prints 2 rather than 5 even after calling update_a() and using global in update_a()
```

2. `config.py`:

```py
a = 2

def update_a():
    global a
    a = 5

def print_a():
    global a
    print(a) # prints 5
```

The global variable in `config.py` does not seem to have the updated value when accessed from `abc.py`.

Comment: use `globals()` to achieve what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do an import say `from .config import *`, the variable `a` is imported as a local scope. Any modification to `a` will happen within the scope in `abc.py` NOT in `config.py` whereas the call to `update_a()` and `print_a()` is modifying the variable `a` within `config.py`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Joe's answer, you can achieve what you want with the following piece of code:

```py
import config as config

config.update_a()
config.print_a() # prints 5

# This will print the global variable in 'config.py'
print(config.a)  # prints 5
```